# How to copy between columns in a df only in empty cells_python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy

I want to copy data from a column to another in the same df. I use copy to do that and it works, the problem is that I assign to the same column values from two different columns and it overlaps. Here is an example

[image]

I want to copy in col1 column, information from id1 column and then, in the empty cells, information from test column without deleting/overlap the values pasted from id1 column

The output should look like this:

[image]

I may have more columns like id1 and test to fill a column like col1(up to 5).
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `first()` value across the columns `axis=1`

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[np.nan]*5,
             "id1":[np.nan,"first","example",np.nan,"secodnd"],
             "test":["test1",np.nan,np.nan,"test2",np.nan],

             })

df = df.assign(col1=df.groupby({c:"first" for c in df.columns}, axis=1).first())
```

### output

```
      col1      id1   test
0    test1      NaN  test1
1    first    first    NaN
2  example  example    NaN
3    test2      NaN  test2
4  secodnd  secodnd    NaN
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to specify the name of the columns that should be paste in col1?

Comment: yes... it's already using an array of all columns `for c in df.columns` `df.columns` can be a static list or you can an an `if` to the comprehension

Comment: I have changed to this and it's working   df = df.assign(col1=df.groupby({c:"first" for c in df[['id1', 'test']] }, axis=1).first())
Thank you so much!

Comment: great , you could use a list to make it simpler `df = df.assign(col1=df.groupby({c:"first" for c in ['id1', 'test'] }`

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple columns like id1, test, you continue with similar fashion like below

```
df['col1'] = df[['id1', 'test']].apply(lambda row: row['id1'] or row['test'],axis=1)
```

Test:

```
test_data = [
{
    'id1': '',
    'test': 'test1'
},
{
    'id1': 'first',
    'test': ''
},{
    'id1': 'example',
    'test': ''
},{
    'id1': '',
    'test': 'test2'
},
{
    'id1': 'second',
    'test': ''
},
]

    df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
    df['col1'] = df[['id1', 'test']].apply(lambda row: row['id1'] or row['test'],axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but it's taking the values from id1 only.

Comment: Should work. I tested and it worked for me.
I have updated my answer to include the test I performed

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `stack()`

```
df['col1'] = df.stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
```

or `ffill()`

```
df['col1'] = df.fillna(method='bfill',axis=1)['col1']
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to specify the name of the columns that should be paste in col1?